# Flutter: Save ToggleButton selection in Shared preferences

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

I have ToggleButton with three selections to select a font, only one selection at a time can be accepted, which is working fine now. But My issue with shared preferences, I am not able to save and get the selection. it is a bit confusing as the outcome of the selection is a list of bools, e.g [true, false, false].

I need your help please to fix the shared preference code so that I can save and get the final selection.

this is my code for shared preferences:

```
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getisSelectedFont();
    isSelectedFont = [true, false, false];
  }

  saveisSelectedFont(bool value) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      prefs.setBool("isSelectedFont", value);
    });
  }

  getisSelectedFont() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      isSelectedFont =
          (prefs.getBool('isSelectedFont') ?? [true, false, false]);
    });
  }

  List<bool> isSelectedFont;
```

and this the code for the ToggleButton:

```
                            child: ToggleButtons(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                              children: <Widget>[
                                // first toggle button
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                      right: 15, left: 15),
                                  child: Text(
                                    'font-1',
                                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                // second toggle button
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                      right: 15, left: 15),
                                  child: Text(
                                    'font-2',
                                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                // third toggle button
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                      right: 15, left: 15),
                                  child: Text(
                                    'font-3',
                                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                              // logic for button selection below

                              onPressed: (int index) {
                                setState(() {
                                  for (int i = 0;
                                      i < isSelectedFont.length;
                                      i++) {
                                    isSelectedFont[i] = i == index;
                                  }
                                });

                                print(isSelectedFont);
                              },
                              isSelected: isSelectedFont,
                            ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class ToggleButtonTest extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ToggleButtonTestState createState() => _ToggleButtonTestState();
}

class _ToggleButtonTestState extends State<ToggleButtonTest> {
  List<bool> isSelectedFont;
  int _currentFontFamily = 0;
  List<String> _fontFamily = [
    'SansitaSwashed',
    'DancingScript',
    'AmanticSC',
  ];
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getisSelectedFont();
    isSelectedFont = [true, false, false];
  }

  saveisSelectedFont() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      prefs.setStringList(
        "isSelectedFont",
        isSelectedFont.map((e) => e ? 'true' : 'false').toList(),
      );
      prefs.setInt('currentFontFamily', _currentFontFamily);
    });
  }

  getisSelectedFont() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      isSelectedFont = (prefs
              .getStringList('isSelectedFont')
              ?.map((e) => e == 'true' ? true : false)
              ?.toList() ??
          [true, false, false]);
      _currentFontFamily = prefs.getInt('currentFontFamily') ?? 0;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Toggle Button Test'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: ToggleButtons(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
              children: <Widget>[
                // first toggle button
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15, left: 15),
                  child: Text(
                    'font-1',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                  ),
                ),
                // second toggle button
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15, left: 15),
                  child: Text(
                    'font-2',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                  ),
                ),
                // third toggle button
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 15, left: 15),
                  child: Text(
                    'font-3',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
              // logic for button selection below
              onPressed: (int index) {
                setState(() {
                  for (int i = 0; i < isSelectedFont.length; i++) {
                    isSelectedFont[i] = i == index;
                  }
                  _currentFontFamily = index;
                  saveisSelectedFont();
                });
              },
              isSelected: isSelectedFont,
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                'This is the answer..',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 30,
                  fontFamily: _fontFamily[_currentFontFamily],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: in order to change the font, create a variable which maintain the index of the font family which is toggle button index too.  set the variable whenever you click the button and save it in shared preferences as well.  read it in getisSelectedFont() which is called in initState().  I have attached the complete code which I tested it.  I hope this will be the answer of the question.

Comment: Excellent, it works well. Thanks Anushath for the answer

Answer (score 1):

change saveisSelectedFont , getisSelectedFont
to this

```
  saveisSelectedFont() async {
   SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
   setState(() {
     prefs.setStringList("isSelectedFont",
         isSelectedFont.map((e) => e ? 'true' : 'false').toList());
   });
}




  getisSelectedFont() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      isSelectedFont = (prefs?.getStringList('isSelectedFont')?.map((e) => e == 'true' ? true : false)?.toList() ?? [true, false, false]);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thank M alkhatib for the support. but not I am not able to use the saved selection, is this correct way of using  `fontFamily: isSelectedFont ==[true, false, false] ? 'Almarai' : 'Dubai',`

Answer (score 0):

```
  saveisSelectedFont() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      prefs.setStringList(
        "isSelectedFont",
        isSelectedFont.map((e) => e ? 'true' : 'false').toList(),
      );
    });
  }

  getisSelectedFont() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      isSelectedFont = (prefs
              .getStringList('isSelectedFont')
              ?.map((e) => e == 'true' ? true : false)
              ?.toList() ??
          [true, false, false]);
    });
  }

  onPressed: (int index) {
    setState(() {
      for (int i = 0; i < isSelectedFont.length; i++) {
        isSelectedFont[i] = i == index;
      }
      saveisSelectedFont();
    });
    
  },
```

Comment: Thanks Anushath, . how can I use it for multiple ternary operators. I tried this but it didn't work : `fontFamily: isSelectedFont == [true, false, false] ? 'Almarai' : isSelectedFont ==  [false, true, false] ? 'Almarai-R' : 'Dubai',`